# Can't see the error

Tags: c, if-statement

For some reason, I can't see where my code is faulty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    printf("How old are you \n");

    scanf("%s", &age);

    if (age > 18){
        printf("You may enter \n");
    }
 /* this above is all that my program runs, always prints "You may enter"*/
  if (age < 18){
        printf("Nothing to see here \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

/*thanks*/

Comment: `scanf("%s", &age);` That's in `int`. use `%d`. And turn up your compiler warnings to pedantic levels and treat them as errors. Modern compilers will flag warnings about format specifier mismatches against provided arguments on something like this.

Comment: `age` is an `int`, not a string,, try `scanf("%d", &age);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

```
$ gcc main.c                                                                   
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s", &age);
           ^
$
```